# Azure AD B2C Single Sign-On Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I am implementing Authentication using Azure AD in C# MVC 5.0 application. I've created Azure AD B2C tenant , My tenant is having three application registered in it.

I would like to implement Single Sign-on so if user is logged in any one of one application he will be directly logged in other applications as well.

I tried to find solutions on the web but found no clear help on how I can start with it and implement.

Any help from the community would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

> if user is logged in any one of one application he will be directly logged in other applications as well

Logging into one of applications doesn't make the user **automatically** logged in in other applications. This happens only **after** the user browses to the application and the SSO protocol takes control over the browser for the handshake sequence.

From the user perspective this doesn't make any difference. They navigate to any of your apps and they are logged in, they usually don't even notice the redirect/response sequence.

Think in terms of a ticket office in a movie theater (the SSO identity provider, Azure in your case) and multiple entrances to the theater (your applications). Buying a ticket (loggin in the identity provider) doesn't automatically make all ticket inspectors aware (you are not automatically logged in everywhere). Rather, when you approach particular entrance and you show your ticket, the particular ticket inspector accepts the ticket and you are allowed to enter (you log into one of applications and it accepts the token from the identity provider) without other inspectors noticing (other applications are not aware you just logged in somewhere).

As for the technical part, Azure implements both OAuth2 and WS-Fed protocols. You can find numerous tutorials on how to integrate a web app using either of the two. If you need assistance in specific technical issues, feel free to create new specific questions. Remember only to focus on specific issues, questions about possible recommendations (*Should I rather use OAuth2 or WS-Fed?* or *Which specific client library should I use for OAuth2?*) don't quite fit here and are likely to be closed.

Comment: Yes Thanks @Wiktor , Sorry for my bad explanation. I meant that only that if user navigate any other application protocol automatically takes control and user will logged in. Could you please give any useful tutorial link which feets for Azure AD B2C tenant ?

Comment: Does this help? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/

Comment: Excellent answer, Wiktor. There is a page describing the SSO scenarios as well - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appssoaccess-whatis/

Answer (score 1):

If you have browser session cookies then you should be able to get SSO across all the app. You should also consider using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client. This library is still under preview.

Comment: Thanks Kanishk.. What I am looking for is general coding structure that we can use using microsoft ADAL library to accomplish it , I don't want to use our custom logic to implement SSO for now, It would be last option

Comment: There are several samples available at https://github.com/azure-samples?query=active-directory